# Why can't I access a USB flash drive? And why does it slow down my computerr?

Tags: desktop-computer, usb-3, devicesanddrives

I have a SanDisk Ultra USB 3.0 flash drive with 128 GB that I use to download videos for my mother. One day, while downloading videos, the USB  flash drive started acting weird. I safely ejected it, then plugged it back in, and the following  happened:

When I tried to open up the files on the USB flash drive, the whole computer slowed down. The file opener kept on loading and loading forever, for hours, and I ended up forcefully pulling out the USB flash drive. After the USB flash drive was removed, everything on the computer was moving at normal speed again.

When I tried to reset the USB  flash drive with all those recommended online methods, it just kept on loading forever with no end in sight.

Is there anything I can do to save this USB flash drive? Or should I just throw it away?

Comment: It is entirely possible that during writing something got corrupted and now when loading the stick the operating system is spinning in a loop trying to read data and failing. Once a stick starts to do this and you cannot format it then it is pretty much game over and you might as well just replace it: https://superuser.com/search?q=USB+cannot+format

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to first attempt to connect it to another computer or device that can read USB storage devices before calling it quits. It might also be worth to have device manager opened as you try this and see if the computer is registering any change at all within the connected devices as it usually refreshes when an USB is plugged in. If you can get any signal at all, it might still be possible to save it using a formatting software, which there are many online